# How to keep Column Names in camel case in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-metastore

select '12345' as `EmpId';

-- output is empid with value 12345

Any leads to keep the same columnname as EmpId?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not possible. This is a limitation of the HIVE metastore. It stores the schema of a table in all lowercase.

Hive uses this method to normalize column names, see [Table.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/Table.java)

```
private static String normalize(String colName) throws HiveException {
    if (!MetaStoreServerUtils.validateColumnName(colName)) {
      throw new HiveException("Invalid column name '" + colName
          + "' in the table definition");
    }
    return colName.toLowerCase();
  }
```

There are a lot of the same `toLowerCase` across all the code. For example [SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java), etc, etc, and it seems it's not easy to change this behaviour because of so many changes in the code required.

Comment: Thank you.. I got it now