# Change Hive External Table Column names to upper case and add new columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, etl, hiveql

I have an external table for example `dump_table`, which is partitioned over year, month and day. If i run `show create table dump_table` i get the following:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `dump_table`
(
  `col_name` double,
  `col_name_2` timestamp
  )
PARTITIONED BY (
  `year` int,
  `month` int,
  `day` int)
CLUSTERED BY (
  someid)
INTO 32 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://somecluster/test.db/dump_table'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'orc.compression'='SNAPPY',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1564476840')
```

I have to change its columns to upper case and also add new columns, so it will become something like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `dump_table_2`
(
  `COL_NAME` DOUBLE,
  `COL_NAME_2` TIMESTAMP,
  `NEW_COL` DOUBLE
  )
PARTITIONED BY (
  `year` int,
  `month` int,
  `day` int)
CLUSTERED BY (
  someid)
```

Option:1

as an option I can run `Change` (DDL Reference [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment)) to change column names and then add new columns to it. BUT the thing is that i do not have any backup for this table and it contains alot of data. If anything goes wrong I might loose data.

Can I create a new external table and migrate data, partition by partition from `dump_table` to `dump_table_2` ? what will the query look like for this migration?

Is there any better way of achieving this use case? Please help

Comment: In older versions of Hive it was not possible to have column names other then lowercased: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57183048/2700344. Maybe everything has already changed in new version... I doubt it

Comment: @leftjoin thank you! so basically all i can do is create a copy of old table, with new columns and migrate data to that new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new table dump_table_2 with new columns and load data using sql:

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert overwrite table dump_table_2 partition (`year`, `month`, `day`)
select col1, 
       ...
       colN,
       `year`, `month`, `day`
  from dump_table_1 t --join other tables if necessary to calculate columns
```

Comment: just one more thing, if i dont specify col list, all identical columns will be migrated and null will be inserted into un-matched columns right? as number of columns are not equal in both tables

Comment: @Dakait You need to specify column list because it is positional. columns will be loaded by positions, not by names. Partition columns should be last in the list. You can use `select *` only if it returns the same columns in the same positions exactly

Comment: `select * ` in my case will return only a subset of columns that are in same position, for example first 10 columns. and i am only interested in those first 10 columns. can i specify list of columns in source and target? Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: @Dakait select col1, col2....colN, NULL as someothercol, NULL as onemoreCol .. partition cols are last

Comment: perfect, I got it now. Appreciate your kind help.