# User Defined Column name in select statement in Hivesql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive, hiveql

I need to create user defined column name like below Postgresql query into HiveSql. Could you please help me on this.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_id) as "Total Customers"
FROM 
    customer_profiles
WHERE
    profiled_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_id) as `Total Customers`
FROM 
 ...
```

But it is not possible to preserve case due to Hive limitation. Resulted column name will be in lower case:

`total customers`

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57183048/2700344

Answer (score 1):

First, just don't put spaces in identifiers.  Use an underscore instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) as Total_Customers
FROM customer_profiles
WHERE profiled_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

This works in all databases and you don't need to fiddle with escape characters.

Second, for date/time comparisons, I strongly recommend that you avoid `BETWEEN`.  Instead:

```
WHERE profiled_date >= '2020-01-01' AND
      profiled_date < '2021-01-01'
```

This works for both dates and date/times.  Your version will filter out records from Dec 31 if they have a time component other than midnight.  Yes, I know in this query you know that there is no time component.  But some day, there will be one, you'll use `BETWEEN` and get the wrong results.